# Php mail script - not including form values in sent email

Tags: php, wordpress, email

I have the a php mail script which gets triggered by the following.

```
var theForm = document.getElementById( 'mailinglist-form' );

new stepsForm( theForm, {
    onSubmit : function( form ) {
    var messageEl = $('.final-message');
        // hide form
        $('.simform-inner').addClass('hide' );
        //remove cursor
        $('#q2').blur();
        //get input field values data to be sent to server
        post_data = {
            'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
            'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val()
        };

        //Ajax post data to server

$.post('mail.php', post_data, function(response){  
        if(response.type == 'error'){

        //load json data from server and output message     
        messageEl.html('Sorry, please try again later.');
        $(messageEl).addClass( 'show' );
            }else{
        messageEl.html(response.text);
        $(messageEl).addClass( 'show' );
        }

        }, 'json');
    }

} );
```

This for calls the following mail.php file

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
$to_email = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Recipient email
$subject = "Mailing list request";
$from = 'anotheremail@gmail.com';    
//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

    $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
        'type'=>'error', 
        'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
    ));
    die($output); //exit script outputting json data
} 

//Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
$user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);

//additional php validation
if(strlen($user_name)<3){ // If length is less than 3 it will output JSON error.
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
    die($output);
}
if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
    die($output);
}
//email body
$message_body = $message."".$user_name." wants to sign up to your mailing list. Details below:\r\n\nName : ".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\n";

//proceed with PHP email.
$headers = 'From: '.$from.'' . "\r\n" .
'Reply-To: '.$from.'' . "\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

$send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

if(!$send_mail)
{
    //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Sorry, please try again later.'));
    die($output);
}else{
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'All done. Thanks for signing up.'));
    die($output);
}
}
?>
```

Now this all seems to work, It sends an email with the users name and email address to the said email "myemail" from "anotheremail".

Whats really weird is that sometime there is no user name or email address just the the rest of the message.

Can anyone tell me whats going on here, I've hit a road block on this one.

thanks and sorry for the poorly formatted code... :P

Comment: What Paul said, but also don't use submitted address as the From address - it will cause you to fail SPF checks. Send it from yoru own address, and use the submitted address as the reply-to, as you're doing. Also, don't tag your questions as PHPMailer if you're not using it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised this just doesn't flat out not work.

`$from = 'anotheremail@gmail.com'`  <- does not have a `;` at the end... Would have thought the php engine to take exception to this.

Comment: Ok sorry, clearly I have the ; in the statement but deleted it for the post. Also they are not the real email addresses I am using. The myemail address is my personal email address that I want the emails to go to. For the from one I just use admin@whateveremail.com.

It works every time I test it, but every now and then we get and email with no details .

Thanks for.you comments regarding phpmailer I will edit